# How to get many terms matched using Hibernate Search query DSL?

Tags: lucene, querydsl, hibernate-search

When I search for "cars blue" I get every result that matches "cars" or "blue", but I need to match them both. I've read about setting some `defaultOperator` to `AND` but I can't find where to do that, 
Also I can't use `PhraseQuery` because the order of the terms in the search query is irrelevant,
This is my code so far, thanks!

```
// create the query using Hibernate Search query DSL
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Articulo.class).get();

// a very basic query by keywords
BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> bool = queryBuilder.bool();

bool.must(queryBuilder.keyword()
    .onFields("description")
    .matching(text)
    .createQuery()
);

Query query = bool.createQuery();

FullTextQuery jpaQuery =
      fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Articulo.class);

return jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

**Note:** I'm using Hibernate Search 5.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the Simple query string feature.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_simple_query_string_queries for more details about it.

You have an example with .withAndAsDefaultOperator():

```
Query luceneQuery = mythQB
    .simpleQueryString()
    .onField("history")
    .withAndAsDefaultOperator()
    .matching("storm tree")
    .createQuery();
```

This blog post explaining the rationale of this feature might be helpful too: http://in.relation.to/2017/04/27/simple-query-string-what-about-it/ .

Comment: Note this requires Hiberenate Search 5.8.0 or later.

Comment: Nice answer but I'm using Hibernate Search 5.6.4.Final because of Spring Boot, is there any workaround?

Comment: Well, you can upgrade your Hibernate Search while still using Spring Boot. But if you want to keep this version, the DSL won't help you. Before the introduction of the Simple Query String feature, I used the MultiFieldQueryParser of Lucene to build the query and pass it to Hibernate Search.